# T-SQL Replace Multiple Values with Wildcards

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, replace, wildcard

I want to replace characters `,` and `/`. I can do this with:

```
DECLARE @OMG VARCHAR(200)
SET @OMG = 'ABC,DE/F'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@OMG,'/','|') ,',','|')
```

The second query does not work however. Is there just typo or the task cannot be achieved with this code? I wanted to use wildcard for set of characters that should be replaced.

```
SELECT REPLACE(@OMG,[,/],'|')
```

It returns:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name ',/'.
```

Comment: "the second option"? Do you mean the second replace? It worked for me. Can you print what you're expecting vs. what you're getting?

Comment: @DLeh I think he's referring to the second query. I bet he's trying to simplify the `REPLACE()` command in order not to pass as parameter the result of the first call of `REPLACE()`, so he wants to replace in one go both the `'` and `,`.

Comment: @DNac Unfortunately that's not [**how REPLACE() works**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: OK, I was wondering whether the REPLACE() function may work with all "characters to be replaced" at once. Thanks.

Comment: @DNac No, only one replace at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all the variables to be replaced and the replacement inside a table use it.

```
create  TABLE #ReplaceStrings (symb VARCHAR(5),replace_char varchar(5))

INSERT INTO #ReplaceStrings
            (symb,replace_char)
VALUES      ('/','|'),(',','|')

DECLARE @OMG VARCHAR(200)

SET @OMG = 'ABC,DE/F'

SELECT @OMG = Replace(@OMG, symb, replace_char)
FROM   #ReplaceStrings

select @OMG
```

Here in a single `replace` you can replace all the unwanted characters.

**Update:** to replace data from table

```
create  TABLE ReplaceStrings (symb VARCHAR(5),replace_char varchar(5))
create  table #table (String varchar(500))
insert into #table values ('ABC,DE/F'),('AB,C,DE/F/')
INSERT INTO ReplaceStrings VALUES ('/','|'),(',','|')
```

**Scalar Function**

```
Create function replacechar(@Ip_String varchar(500))
returns varchar(500)
begin
SELECT @Ip_String=Replace(@Ip_String, symb, replace_char) 
FROM   ReplaceStrings
return @Ip_String
end
```

Execute the function

```
select String,dbo.replacechar(String) Replaced_String from #table
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks for the answer. By the way how does it happen the query "knows" that it should use both rows from #ReplaceStrings? Whats the execution plan? I want to understand it's principle.

Comment: @DNac string will be replaced twice in this query. First `/` will be replaced in the first row and `,` will be replaced in second row. Always the last row will be assigned to the string`(@OMG)` so will get the final replaced string

Comment: And there is no need to specify any kind of `LOOP`? SQL knows itself it should cycle whole #ReplaceStrings table?

Comment: @DNac - no you don't have to loop. All the characters present in the `#ReplaceStrings` temp table will be replaced.

Comment: OK, final question: If I have the data in other table, how to "join" it with this solution? E.g. `SELECT * FROM TST` will give me `ABC,DE/F`. Can I still connect it to the solution with Temp Table?

Comment: @DNac Convert the above code to `scalar valued function` use it in the table. If you have any doubts i can write one

Comment: If you could, it will be great as I am pretty new to SQL and dont know UDFs yet. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @DNac - Updated check now

Comment: Thanks for your effort.